# integrate $\int \frac{\sin^3x \cos^2x}{1+\sin^2x}dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{\sin^3x \cos^2x}{1+\sin^2x}dx$$

$$\int \frac{\sin^3x \cos^2x}{1+\sin^2x}dx=\int \frac{\sin^2x \cos^2x  \sin x }{1+\sin^2x}dx=\int \frac{(1-\cos^2x )\cos^2x  \sin x }{1+1-\cos^2x}dx=\int \frac{(1-\cos^2x )\cos^2x  \sin x }{2-\cos^2x}dx$$

$u=cosx$

$du=-sinxdx$

$$-\int \frac{(1-u^2 )u^2}{2-u^2}du=\int \frac{u^4-u^2 }{2-u^2}du$$

Polynomial division give us

$$\int-u^2-1+\frac{2}{u^2-2}du=-\frac{u^3}{3}-u=2\int \frac{1}{u^2-2}du$$

Using partial fraction we get to:

$$\frac{1}{u^2-2}=\frac{1}{(u+\sqrt{2})(u^2-\sqrt{2})}=\frac{A}{u^2+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{B}{u^2-\sqrt{2}}$$

So we get to:

$$1=(A+B)u^2+\sqrt{2}(A-B)$$

So $A=B$ but $0*\sqrt{2}\neq 1$, where did it go wrong?

Comment: $A=-B=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$

Comment: At polynomial division

Comment: $(u^4-u^2)/(2-u^2)=-u^2-1+2/(\color{red}{2-u^2})$.

Comment: @mathlove but If I muliple the fraction by minus, just the numerator or the denominator are multiplied, not both

Comment: And why not use triangle substitution to solve $\int \frac{1}{u^2-2}du?$ Like $u=\sqrt2 \sin x?$

Comment: @AhmedHussein The polynomial division is correct.

Comment: @egreg if we work out the expression obtained, we get $\frac{u^4 - u^2 - 2}{2 - u^2}$. How is this correct?

Comment: @AhmedHussein. $\frac{u^4-u^2}{2-u^2}$ is correct (at least to me).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici no, what I mean is that if we work out the expression obtained at "polynomial division" (i.e. $- u^2 - 1 + \frac2{u^2 - 2}$), we get $\frac{u^4 - u^2 - 2}{2 - u^2}$ (hence that this is the step at which things went wrong)

Comment: @AhmedHussein Indeed, there's a sign wrong. But it's a minor slip: the real problem is in the partial fractions.

Comment: Substitute $\sin^4 x=z$. Then the integral becomes, $$\dfrac{1}{4}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dz}{1+\sqrt{z}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
\frac{t^2-t}{2-t}=(-1-t)+\frac{2}{2-t}
$$
so your integral is
$$
\int\left(-\frac{2}{u^2-2}-u^2-1\right)\,du
$$
and your reduction is (almost) good, but a sign went wrong. Now your computation of partial fractions is really messed up:
$$
\frac{2}{u^2-2}=\frac{A}{u-\sqrt{2}}+\frac{B}{u+\sqrt{2}}
$$
so you get
$$
\begin{cases}
A+B=0\\[6px]
A\sqrt{2}-B\sqrt{2}=2
\end{cases}
$$
so $A=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $B=-1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Why is it $-\frac{2}{2-t}$ and not$\frac{2}{2-t}$?

Comment: @gbox I copied the signs wrong.

Comment: I got the end result of  $-\frac{cos^3x}{3}-cosx-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}ln|\sqrt{2}-cosx|+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}ln|\sqrt{2}+cosx|+c$

Answer (score 2):

The decomposition in partial fractions should be
$$\frac{1}{u^2-2}==\frac{A}{u +\sqrt{2}}+\frac{B}{u -\sqrt{2}}.$$

*But* every one should know that
$$\int\frac1{a^2-x^2}\,\mathrm d x=\frac1{2a}\ln\biggl\lvert\frac{x+a}{x-a}\biggr\rvert=\frac1a\,\operatorname{argtanh}\Bigl(\frac xa\Bigr).$$

Comment: It is a looong time I did not see **argtanh** ! Is it on purpose or a typo ? If this is want you wanted to type, I am ready to bet about your age and where you did learn it. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: What I should indeed have typed  is $\operatorname{argth}$…

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{\sin^3(x)\cos^2(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Use $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$:

---

$$-\int\frac{\sin(x)(\cos^2(x)-\cos^4(x))}{\cos^2(x)-2}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\cos(x)$ and $\text{d}u=-\sin(x)\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\int\frac{u^2-u^4}{u^2-2}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Use long division:

---

$$-\int\left[u^2+1+\frac{2}{u^2-2}\right]\space\text{d}u=$$
$$-\left[\int u^2\space\text{d}u+\int1\space\text{d}u+2\int\frac{1}{u^2-2}\space\text{d}u\right]=$$
$$-\left[\frac{u^3}{3}+u-\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{u^2}{2}}\space\text{d}u\right]=$$

---

Substitute $s=\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\text{d}s=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\space\text{d}u$:

---

$$-\left[\frac{u^3}{3}+u-\sqrt{2}\int\frac{1}{1-s^2}\space\text{d}s\right]=$$
$$-\left[\frac{u^3}{3}+u-\sqrt{2}\text{arctanh}(s)\right]+\text{C}=$$
$$-\left[\frac{\cos^3(x)}{3}+\cos(x)-\sqrt{2}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that, $$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin^3 x\cos^2 x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin^3 x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx-\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin^5 x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx$$

> **Transformation of $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin^3 x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx$**

Observe that $\cos^2 x=z\implies \sin x\ dx=-\dfrac{dz}{2}$. Then the integral becomes, $$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin^3 x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx=-\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{1-z}{2-z}dz$$

> **Transformation of $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin^5 x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx$**

Observe that $\cos^2 x=z\implies \sin x\ dx=-\dfrac{dz}{2}$. Then the integral becomes, $$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin^5 x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx=-\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{(1-z)^2}{2-z}dz$$

---

I hope you can evaluate both the integrals easily.